# Need to fetch a value from JSON stored in a CLOB in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, json, regex, oracle, oracle11g

I need to fetch the `patientInfo` property from JSON which is in a CLOB. In some cases the `patientInfo` can be null. Is there any regular expression pattern to fetch the property `patientInfo` from the CLOB?

```
{
   "id":"12",
   "name":"xx",
   "patientInfo":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "name":"yy"
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "name":"zz"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Where does 'raw' fit in? And can you use [the PL/JSON library](https://github.com/pljson/pljson) - presumably this isn't the only JSON manipulation you need to do?

Comment: As of now, we are fetching the entire CLOB and doing some validations in the JAVA level, it will be better if I have in the Query part(i.e to fetch only the patientinfo property)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 12c you can use [JSON_QUERY](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6277) to extract some values from JSON, 
below is a very simple example:

```
create table ttt(
  my_json clob
);

insert into ttt( my_json ) values(
q'[{
   "id":"12",
   "name":"xx",
   "patientInfo":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "name":"yy"
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "name":"zz"
      }
   ]
}]'
);

commit;
```

---

And now:

```
select json_query(my_json, '$.patientInfo') as result
from ttt
```

gives this result:

```
RESULT  
-----------------------------------------------
[{"id":"1","name":"yy"},{"id":"2","name":"zz"}]
```

Comment: Not sure that really helps with a question about 11g... *8-)